# How to deal with filling a structure in c language

Tags: c

I am having problems understanding how to call and store information into structures.

```
typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double price;
} StockPrice;

typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double shares;
} Stock;


typedef struct {
    Stock myStocks[MAX_MY_STOCKS]; // MAX_MY_STOCKS is five.
    double balance;
} Portfolio;
```

I don't know exactly how to word it but i'm dealing with a structure that has another type of struct in it and would like to know how to fill and print out the structure when writing in C language.

Comment: Are you asking about the basics of accessing a nested struct (i.e. how to use the `.` operator twice)? Or are you asking about how to initialise a variable of nested struct type?

Comment: For the part about printin, please provide a code frame, i.e. a program which defines and initialises a variable of the type in question and a placeholder for printing it. Then show the desired output for the sample data. That will help to clarify what exactly you are stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

> how to call and store information into structures

You don't *call* structure. You *access* it. I understand (as I assume) that you are a beginner in C and its alright to use wrong terms initially, but going ahead you need to know some stuff so that you can at least explain your problems :-)

```
typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double price;
} StockPrice;

typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double shares;
} Stock;

typedef struct {
    Stock myStocks[MAX_MY_STOCKS]; // MAX_MY_STOCKS is five.
    double balance;
} Portfolio;
```

First thing you'll need is an object of the type `Portfolio`.

```
Portfolio myPortfolio;
```

Now you have an object of the structure.
To *access* (Read and Write) structure members, you can use `.` operator.

So,

```
myPortfolio.balance = 12.35;
```

Will set the value of `balance` to `12.35`.
Similarly, if you want to set the value of `shares` in 3<sup>rd</sup> index of `myStock`, you can do this:

```
myPortfolio.myStock[3].shared = 111.222;
```

To start with, you'll need to understand how to and when to use the `.` and `->` operators. 
C11 standard has ample information on it. Although in the beginning referring to standard can be very confusing as one may not be well-versed with the terms, but it does help.
Read through section [stucture and union members](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3) to see what C standard states.

So, a bad code to write and read those values:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_MY_STOCKS   5

typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double price;
} StockPrice;

typedef struct {
    char ticker[10];
    double shares;
} Stock;

typedef struct {
    Stock myStocks[MAX_MY_STOCKS]; // MAX_MY_STOCKS is five.
    double balance;
} Portfolio;

Portfolio myPortfolio;

void PrintPortfolio(unsigned int Index)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(Index >= MAX_MY_STOCKS)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nStock overflow :D");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");    

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\nticker %d in myStock[%d] is %X", i, Index, myPortfolio.myStocks[Index].ticker[i]);    
    }

    printf("\nshares in myStock[%d] is %lf", Index, myPortfolio.myStocks[Index].shares);
}

int main(void) 
{
    myPortfolio.balance = 12.34;
    myPortfolio.myStocks[3].shares = 111.222;

    printf("My portfolio balance is %lf", myPortfolio.balance);

    for(int i = 0; i < (MAX_MY_STOCKS+1); i++)   // The deliberate extra iteration, a bit of a pun! :D
    {
        PrintPortfolio(i);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n Lets use a pointer!");
    Portfolio *pmyPortfolio;
    pmyPortfolio = &myPortfolio;
    printf("\n\nMy portfolio balance is %lf", pmyPortfolio->balance);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since WedaPashi didn't cover Initializing with values I'll briefly explain. Once you declare a struct

```
StockPrice sp;
```

Then there is now a section of memory for all the variables in that struct. Right now all those variables have 'garbage values' meaning they could be any possible value and we can't reliably know what. As mentioned in his answer you can access the values with '.' in order to assign a value to them such as

```
sp.price = 12.35;
```

you can initialize arrays in the same way so we could say

```
sp.ticker = {'t','i','c','k','e','r','V','A','L'};
```

or in the special case of char arrays we can simply say

```
sp.ticker = "tickerVal";
```

or alternatively you can initialize all values in the struct at once such as

```
StockPrice sp = {"tickerVal", 99.35};
```

at this point sp.price is equal to 99.35, and ticker contains the string "tickerVal".
Its important to note that once at least one variable has its value set in the struct then all other variables that haven't had a value assigned get a defualt value. In other words once you set at least one variable then there won't be any more 'garbage values.'

If we want to throw this all together just to give you an idea of more complex initilizations we can say something like this:

```
Portfolio p = { 
    /*first value is an array initialization of stocks*/
    {
        {"ticker0\0",0.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker1\0",1.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker2\0",2.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker3\0",3.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker4\0",4.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker5\0",5.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker6\0",6.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker7\0",7.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker8\0",8.0},     /*stock structs*/
        {"ticker9\0",9.0}      /*stock structs*/
    },/*end of array of Stock*/
    /*second value is double balance*/
    100.99
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // filling by initialisation in source code:
    Stock a = { .ticker = "Whatever" // caution: You only have *nine* characters;
              , .shares = 0.0                 // you need the string terminator...
              };
    printf("Stock a has ticker %s and shares %f\n", a.ticker, a.shares);

    // classic reassignment:
    // you don't want to know...

    // classic reassignment v1.5:
    snprintf(a.ticker, sizeof a.ticker, "%s", "Meh");
    a.shares = 42.0;

    // reassignment v2:
    a = (Stock){ "under ten", -1. }; // as in "under ten" characters long!

    // reassignment v2.5
    a = (Stock){ .shares = 9001.
               , .ticker = "to the moon" // Zap! Nine characters or less, remember?!
               };

    // read from console:
    while (scanf("%9[^ ] %lf", a.ticker, &a.shares) == 2) {
        printf("You entered the ticker: { %9s, %lf }\n", a.ticker, a.shares);
    }
}
```